# A link that doesn't work, even if the source is ok

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, url

I don't understand what is going on!

I have this page on my website with an url that point to the personal website of the user:
http://www.recettesmaison.ca/Profile/Details/Sandra

The url is ok in the source:

```
<h5>Site web personnel</h5>
<a href="www.vitaminesetmarmitons.com">www.vitaminesetmarmitons.com</a>
```

But if you try to click on it in the page itself, it goes to:

```
http://www.recettesmaison.ca/Profile/Details/www.vitaminesetmarmitons.com
```

If the user update his website and put `http://` before the `www`, then the link works ok...

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing your protocol:

```
<a href="www.vitaminesetmarmitons.com">www.vitaminesetmarmitons.com</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="http://www.vitaminesetmarmitons.com">www.vitaminesetmarmitons.com</a>
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté Without the protocol, the browser assumes you're meaning to go to a different resource on the same server, which you have already discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Put `http://` in front of the URL. Otherwise the browser will interpret it as a relative link, not an absolute one.

```
<a href="http://www.vitaminesetmarmitons.com">www.vitaminesetmarmitons.com</a>
         ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add `http://` in the beginning of link address

without http (Protocol) the link supposed as folder